# how to build {} tags before and end of template tags in php template

Tags: php, templates, frameworks, tags

I wanna build my own framework for my business but i can't find any suggestion in internet. Cause i'm not an IT, i just love web developer and i learn from internet.

It's like WP template tags `<? template_title(); ?>`
// But i don't wanna use this.
Or Django as `{% template_tags() %}`

I wanna build my own open tag is `{` or `[[`.

```
[[ template_tags ]] is <?php template_tags; ?>
```

Any suggestion? Special thanks.

Comment: I think you need to learn the base languages like c, c++ or java for this. Creating your own syntax is like creating your own compiler. So, why not start there? :D.

Comment: Start in phython or c language.

Comment: Thanks all. I think I just need to use str_replace. That's enough.